# How to add voices to AI program in python

Tags: python, windows-10, pyttsx3

I have made an AI using python and the default voice for text to speech is set as Microsoft David but when i try to change it there are only two voices whereas i have installed others also from settings which are not shown there.

Any chance to add  more voices.

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44858120/how-to-change-the-voice-in-pyttsx3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well there is a good reason for this.

pyttsx3 can only access the voices at `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Speech\Voices\Tokens\`

However this has to do with registry files so you should really be careful if you do not know with what you are messing around.
There is probably the answer you are looking for.
[voice/language change pyttsx3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57669336/problem-with-voice-language-change-with-pyttsx3/66025879#66025879)

**WARNING**

Please before trying anything backup your registry files or even your system if you do not know with what you are messing around.